# Search widget call OnNewIntent twice

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-search

I have an activity in which I want to search. When I click to search, event `OnNewIntent` it is called twice... What I'm doing wrong?

I'm creating Searchview like this

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu) 
{

    searchView = new SearchView(this);
    var searchManager = (SearchManager)GetSystemService(Context.SearchService);
    var searchableInfo = searchManager.GetSearchableInfo(ComponentName);

    searchView.SetSearchableInfo(searchableInfo);
    var search_item = menu.Add(new Java.Lang.String("Search"));
    search_item.SetActionView(searchView);
    search_item.SetShowAsAction(ShowAsAction.IfRoom);        

    var edit = menu.Add(0, insertItemID, 0, "Insert");
    edit.SetShowAsAction(ShowAsAction.IfRoom);
    edit.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcMenuAdd);

    return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
}
```

Log:

```
10-17 07:45:45.491 I/ActivityManager(  900): START {act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=Intranet.Intranet/intranet.screens.ContactListActivity (has extras)} from pid 2971
10-17 07:45:47.562 W/EGL_emulation( 2971): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-17 07:45:47.562 I/ActivityManager(  900): START {act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=Intranet.Intranet/intranet.screens.ContactListActivity (has extras)} from pid 2971
10-17 07:45:48.472 D/OpenGLRenderer( 2971): Flushing caches (mode 0)
10-17 07:45:48.481 D/dalvikvm(  900): GC_CONCURRENT freed 559K, 13% free 7991K/9159K, paused 1ms+1ms
10-17 07:45:48.500 W/InputManagerService(  900): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b48b3470
10-17 07:45:48.561 D/dalvikvm(  963): GC_CONCURRENT freed 389K, 41% free 6027K/10183K, paused 0ms+0ms
```

Comment: where is search onClick method? please post it also

Comment: Probably not related but you should return true from onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem?

Comment: c1rus, droidster, can you tell me on what device you found this problem? I can reproduce it only on Genymotion emulator but not on any other device (S3, S4, Galaxy Nexus running 4.0.4, Nexus 7 running 4.3)

Answer (score 18):

I assume you have made your search activity single top  and overidden onNewIntent to call setIntent prior to processing the search intent.  If so, it's a bug in SearchView when using the emulator hardware keyboard.

http://books.google.com/books?id=OFXJXbCXjTgC&pg=PT771&lpg=PT771&dq=android+search+intent+sent+twice+bug&source=bl&ots=Ora1AJjh4A&sig=9yFBjCwJ1ARbXePHzcPYpG_QdFQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bbddUpbZCcLi4AOiioCIAw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=android%20search%20intent%20sent%20twice%20bug&f=false

You can disable the hardware keyboard in your emulator by going to Settings -> Launguage & input and click on Default.

If you use the soft keyboard you should only see it once.

Comment: happened on my genymotion virtual device on physiscal nexus never this bug has occured. PS. good tip is to put some logs in that method to be sure all is OK.

Comment: How can I enable the soft keyboard in the genymotion emulator?

Comment: Still happening. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with DatePickerDialog...it seems to be an api bug. It works on android 2.2, but not on android 4.0+. My solution was:

```
int timesCalled = 0;
public void yourMethod(){
    timesCalled += 1;
    if ((timesCalled % 2) == 0) {
       //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Its not the clearest solution, but it works for me. Hope this can help.

Comment: `(timesCalled%2)` means it should be called an even number of times, you want to do your stuff if it is called even number of times?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try something like this...

https://github.com/antoniolg/LimeApp/blob/master/src/com/limecreativelabs/app/actionbarsearch/ActionBarSearchActivity.java

the example app of the project is here....

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.limecreativelabs.app

and you can read the project specifications in here...

https://github.com/antoniolg/LimeApp